# Need to control order of include files building a CCFI shared library

Tags: c, header, cffi

I am trying to build a shared library with CFFI for one of the Linux core utilities that I can call from Python. I have done this before for other C and C++ programs but this is my first attempt for one of the core utilities.

I finished modifying the utility's C code to provide a callable routine and I successfully tested it as a command-line program. The problem occurs when I attempt to compile it using CFFI.

When CFFI builds the C code to compile, it inserts a lengthy prefix of several hundred lines including an include of <Python.h> before it embeds the code of the core utility. This is normal but the core utilities include a header <config.h> that must precede other headers. The specific error I get is "Please include config.h first." generated by the header <unistd.h> which was included from the Python.h header.

Does CFFI provide a way to modify the prefix that it generates so that I can stick <config.h> in it before the Python.h include? I suppose I could discover a way to modify one of more headers to get around this problem but I'd like to avoid modifications like that. What is the best way to get around this problem?

Comment: If you're using GCC or Clang, maybe the `-include` option will help.  See [GCC Preprocessor Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- Thank you. I use gcc and that solved the problem. Its use led to another problem I am still trying to understand.I use Geany for source code editing and Python execution testing -- I rarely use it for C and C++ builds. When I run the CFFI build script from Geany, the compiler can't find the header included via the -include option. When I copy and paste the gcc command that CFFI builds into a terminal shell, it works OK. I am being careful to ensure execution takes place in the same directory. Obviously there is a good reason but I have not yet figured out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GCC or Clang, the `-include filename` option might help.
It includes the named file before anything else.
See [GCC Preprocessor Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Answer (score 0):

I am following up with an answer to my question just in case someone else discovers this post through a search on how to control the include order while building a CFFI shared library.

The CFFI .set_source method has an 'extra_compile_args' parameter that allows setting GCC options like the -include option suggested by Jonathan Leffler. That should have solved the problem (so I marked his answer as the solution) but it didn't. It lead to another problem that I mentioned in my comment above and that I posted in another question here ([GCC complains 'No such file or directory" but the file exists and its name is typed correctly -- truly -- so what's the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159589/gcc-complains-no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists-and-its-name-is-ty)).

No solution could be found to solve that problem so I came up with a way to get around it. I created a small Python.h header in the same directory with my source code and put two include statements in it -- an include of the header that had to come before all other headers and an include of the real Python.h header. The actual Python header is referenced through its absolute path, which means there is a maintenance issue when another version of Python is used.

There is one other issue I encountered that I mention because the problem I asked about here is directly related to (and may be somewhat unique to) my project, which is to build a shared library with Python bindings for one of the linux core utilities. If you find this post, you may be trying to do something similar. The static library libcoreutils.a is needed but it is built without the GCC option -fPIC and that option is required to build a shared library. Comments in the coretuils makefile indicate the omission of this option is intentional to avoid potential problems on at least 64-bit systems. In other words, you will have to build your own PIC replacement for this library.