# GCC complains 'No such file or directory" but the file exists and its name is typed correctly -- truly -- so what's the problem?

Tags: c, gcc, include

I am using Geany and CFFI to build a shared library written in C. When I execute the CFFI build script in Geany, it generates GCC statements to compile the code to object and then link the result. I am using the GCC -include option to specify the complete, absolute path of a header file. When the GCC compile runs, it complains that it cannot find that file.

By setting the CFFI compile verbose option to True, the script prints the complete GCC statement to screen in a terminal emulator (gnome-terminal). When I copy that statement and paste it into another emulated terminal (also gnome-terminal), the compile runs successfully. I think this proves the file exists and that its name has been entered correctly.

The working directory for both terminal windows is the same but that should not matter since the header filename is an absolute path. Why different results with the two executions of GCC?

I need successful execution in the Geany terminal window so that CFFI's script will continue to the next step of linking the shared library.

Comment: "When I copy that statement and paste it into another emulated terminal (also gnome-terminal), the compile runs successfully. I think this proves the file exists and that its name has been entered correctly." <-- Not true.  Pipe the output of the build script through `cat -v` and I predict you will discover invisible characters that did not survive the copy and paste.

Comment: If the filenames have relative paths, you're probably not in the correct starting directory.

Comment: @zwol Thanks for the suggestion. I piped the script output to cat -v and did not see any non-printable character. I also piped the output to a file and examined it with a hex editor - the include file name is exactly as it appears on screen -- also exactly as I entered the name in the file that builds the script. I copied that file output and pasted it into an emulated terminal window and it ran successfully.

Comment: @ Barmar. The filename has an absolute path as I explained. Also, even though I don't think it matters because an absolute path is used, I verified both executions took place in the same working directory.

Comment: My next suggestion is gonna be that you shim the internal `cc1` binary and make it run under `strace` so you can see what the failing system call actually is... (yes, that's going to be a pain in the butt, I don't think I can explain how to do it in the space of a comment)

Comment: @zwol -- Let me take a shot and what I think you mean, which is to put some thing XX between  gcc and cc1 so that when gcc tries to invoke cc1 it actually calls XX, then XX runs cc1 under strace. Is that the basic idea? If so, one way I can think of to do that is to temporarily rename cc1 (to cc1X) and give XX the executable name of cc1 -- or somehow put XX earlier in the path. Is this even close to what your are thinking?

Comment: Yes, that's more or less how I'd do it.

Comment: @zwol No joy. I renamed cc1 to cc1Target and wrote a program cc1 using execv to call strace cc1Target. The compile failed with "internal compiler error." The traceback shows DistutilsExecError in _spawn_posix. I tried the same thing with gcc; this fails as before reporting the include file can't be found but since the error occurs in cc1 I have no trace details. The include filename printed on the screen looks correct; by that I mean no spurious characters. I am open to trying other things. I really would like to discover what is the problem and hopefully solve it or get around it.

Comment: @dave I regret to say I don't think I can help you troubleshoot this any further. We are well into "pay a GCC developer consulting rates to come to your office in person and debug your installation" territory here.